# Unable to read/write raster/shapefile into R on a company computer

Tags: r, r-raster

I know this problem is quite frequent because I've read so many questions on so many forums but I couldn't find any solution. 
I have to manipulate rasters and shapefiles for my work. Everything is going fine on my personal laptop, the code is running, but as soon as I try it on my company desktop it doesn't work anymore. Every time I try to open a raster I get the following error :

```
> raster("/Users/WB513210/Desktop/ID1.tif")
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
TIFFReadDirectory:Failed to read directory at offset 8

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

If I try to open a shapefile then I have the following error :

```
> shp<-readOGR(dsn = paste0(path,"Final Capital Exposure/"), layer = "Dom10_Modified_AssetValue2")
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
Cannot open data source
```

Finally if I try to export a raster I've created directly into R it doesn't work either.

I've checked many things I've seen in some answers :

- The files are not corrupted for sure, I can read them in ArcMap and use them with R on my personal laptop
- I tried without the underscores, it does not change anything
- Ive tried every version of R, it does not change anything.
- My libraries are up-to-date.
- I tried to put the file in different folders (document, desktop, etc...)

What is weird is that I can manipulate csv or xlsx for instance, load them, write them etc. But nothing with rgdal and raster libraries. Could this be linked to the security system established on the computer by the company ? I tried with some IT guy to install the library not on my personal session but on the whole computer with administrator rights, but it did not change anything.

I'm working on windows 10 Enterprise. Have you heard about any thing between R and windows 10 enterprise ?

Finally i'm using R 3.3.1 for now but I've tried with the latest version it did not work either.

If you have any clue, I'll take it !

Thank you in advance for your help,

Titou

Comment: Have you tried `raster("C:/Users/WB513210/Desktop/ID1.tif")`?

Comment: Have you tried doing it on a different computer at work?

Comment: it works fine on win7

Comment: have you tried replacing `/` with `\\ `?

Comment: I tried C: and to replace / with \\ but it did not change anything.
Patrick, yeah I've tried on other computer it did not work either !